# Choose C++ template to call based on runtime variable

Tags: c++, templates

I have a c++ code piece look like this:

```
void SaveDataInTxt(DataFormat fmt, const char *data, size_t size) {
    switch (fmt.bit_width) {
    case 8: return SaveDataInTxtImpl<int8_t>(data, size);
    case 16: return SaveDataInTxtImpl<int16_t>(data, size);
    case 32: return SaveDataInTxtImpl<int32_t>(data, size);
    }
}
```

Just wonder is there any better way to get rid of this switch case statement and put the body of SaveDataInTxtImpl() directly inside SaveDataInTxt().

Thanks!

Comment: Probably not, that's how template dispatching can be implemented. you have to instantiate all cases. Int he case of an integer, a switch is probably the most efficient solution.

Comment: Instead of `DataFormat` having a variable that specifies bit width, you could make it a template type which contains the bit width, then allow the template engine to select the right `SaveDataInTxt` implementation based on that. If don't know the data type ahead of time though, you'd have to do something like what you have here at some point in your code.

Comment: semi-offtopic: return type is declared to be `void`, wont compile

Comment: @user463035818 not if `SaveDataInTxtImpl` returns void as well.

Comment: I think this can be done using type-traits. But wonder if the effort is worth it.

Comment: Honestly, I think you are aiming to fix something that isn't broken. It's a short descriptive function that quite clearly translates runtime values to compile time functions. The function template already makes it DRY, and this bit is mandatory overhead. I'd just let it go if I were you.

Comment: switch could be replaced by `map`, but idea is the same at the end.

Comment: If you aren’t relying on template argument deduction in the call, you can separate the *selection* of the `Impl` specialization from the *call*.  This is more useful when the argument list is longer, of course.